# Moment js is not giving days properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am using angular with moment js to get date difference but it is not giving right number of days,

```
  module.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', '$mdDatePicker', function($scope, $mdDatePicker) {
    this.startDate = function(ev) {
      $mdDatePicker(ev, $scope.startDate).then(function(selectedDate) {
        $scope.startDate = selectedDate;

        var now = selectedDate;
        var then = $scope.endDate;
        var ms = moment(now, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
        var d = moment.duration(ms);
        $scope.dateDifferenceDays = d.asDays();
      });
    }
    this.endDate = function(ev) {
      $mdDatePicker(ev, $scope.endDate).then(function(selectedDate) {
        $scope.endDate = selectedDate;

        var now = $scope.startDate;
        var then = selectedDate;
        var ms = moment(now, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
        var d = moment.duration(ms);
        $scope.dateDifferenceDays = d.asDays();
      });
    }
  }]);
```

Here is full codepen i am developing - [Codepen](http://codepen.io/alimista15/pen/WvRXOx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use duration for this. Directly use the second parameter of diff to get the difference as days :

```
$scope.dateDifferenceDays = moment(now, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"), 'days');
```

Comment: Thanks but it is giving me wrong number of days though, if you check here - http://prntscr.com/7b2qyz

Comment: number of days should be 1037 not 1067 as when used with this dates - now Sat May 30 2015 12:09:25 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) then = Sun Apr 01 2018 12:09:32 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

Comment: Might be an issue with your code, check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kxoqrqoz/

Comment: yes it's issue with the format it's getting date from